# Why I get the error: "Attempted to unrender a fragment that was not rendered" when migrating from ractive.js 0.3.9 to 0.5.5

Tags: migration, javascript, template-engine, ractivejs

I have a long, complex and a little dirty set of templates that works OK in 0.3.9 but not in 0.5.5 where I get the error: "Attempted to unrender a fragment that was not rendered".

My template is very complex but I could reproduce a slice that works in 0.3.9 but not in 0.5.5.

This is how it works OK in 0.3.9: http://jsfiddle.net/Katio/ujx2e/

This template in 0.5.5 shows the mentioned error: http://jsfiddle.net/Katio/W3Lus/

```
Attempted to unrender a fragment that was not rendered
```

Edit 1:

Thaylon has opened an issue in Ractive project on Github:
https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit I'm not sure what the root of the problem is.

Yet, change the beginning of line 33 in your template from:

```
{{^.responsable}}<span class="redOutline" data-validationmess="Solicitud ({{num+1}}) '{{../../nombreSubdata.values[0]}}', secci&oacute;n '{{nombre.values[0]}}', responsable no asignado.">(responsable no asignado)</span>{{/.responsable}}
```

to:

```
{{^responsable}}<span class="redOutline" data-validationmess="Solicitud ({{num+1}}) '{{../../nombreSubdata.values[0]}}', secci&oacute;n '{{nombre.values[0]}}', responsable no asignado.">(responsable no asignado)</span>{{/responsable}}
```

and it will render.

http://jsfiddle.net/W3Lus/2/

**Edit**

A pretty minimal example that exhibits the error is: http://jsfiddle.net/W3Lus/9/

Removing any part, even the static `<option>`, it will render.

Doesnt look like you're doing anything wrong, seems to be a bug.

**Edit**

I assume binding the select value to {{.responsable}}, when it does not resolve to anything, causes this, as long as there is any option in the select that actually would be bound to the non-existing value.

**Edit**

Minimal examples with different buggy results: 
http://jsfiddle.net/W3Lus/13/
http://jsfiddle.net/W3Lus/12/

One wont render at all, the other wont render a part that it should.

Comment: You removed a dot, and the template renders! However the dot is very important for the validation in the template because it must validate each element in an array. Anyway it's nice that you've found the exact line in the template with the problem.

Comment: After your discovery I tried to create a smaller version of the problem that isolates it. So I used the ^dot again
    {{^.responsable}}
with 0.5.5 but it works OK http://jsfiddle.net/W3Lus/5/
I don't get it

Comment: I inserted the original partial in your new example and the error is there again. http://jsfiddle.net/W3Lus/7/

Comment: Thank you. You answered my question, Now it seems a bug in 0.5.5 because your minimal example works OK in version 0.3.9: http://jsfiddle.net/W3Lus/16/ but shows the error "Attempted to unrender a fragment that was not rendered" in 0.5.5: http://jsfiddle.net/W3Lus/13/